# Failed To Remove Duplicate Value From Android ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database, so I have  made a query to get images based on tag query. But after getting data from database when I try to add it in array list. I gives me duplicate value. I dont know whether it is a firebase problem or java problem. image0 and image 1 are added twice. I have tried to clear duplicate value using Hashset. Another strange thing is that loop is iterating only two times, i have checked it using counter.[image]

```
private void searchInWallpapers(){
    Query wallpaperquery = myRef.child("wallpapers").orderByChild("tag").equalTo(keyWord);
    wallpaperquery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int i = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot eachImage : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ImageModelClass  data2 = new ImageModelClass(eachImage.child("imgUrl").getValue().
                        toString(),eachImage.child("like").getValue().toString(),eachImage.child("title").getValue().toString());
                resultList.add(data2);

            }

            Set<ImageModelClass> set = new HashSet<>(resultList);
            resultList.clear();
            resultList.addAll(set);
            imageListAdapter imageListAdapter = new imageListAdapter(search_result.this,resultList);
            resultRecycler.setAdapter(imageListAdapter);
            FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(search_result.this);
            layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.SPACE_AROUND);
            layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
            resultRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: 'loop is iterating only two times', only two nodes in your fig, so loop twice is right, isn't it?

Comment: yes it should iterate two times, but why it is adding data twice.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that you are adding data to your list "resultList" without clear it

you need to add the code like

```
if (resultList == null)
        resultList = new ....
    else
        resultList.clear();

    int i = 0;
    for (DataSnapshot eachImage : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        ImageModelClass data2 = new ImageModelClass(eachImage.child("imgUrl").getValue().
                toString(), eachImage.child("like").getValue().toString(), eachImage.child("title").getValue().toString());
        resultList.add(data2);
    }
```

then no need to process to remove duplicate values

Comment: no I can't clear the data,because I am adding data from firebase from different node, in that case data is not repeating. Only in this case means searchInWallpaer method data is repeating in array list. Very strange thing.

Comment: there is might be possible that the listener you are registering to query might be called multiple time as data changes that it can be possible to multiple values as Data changed method fired, just confirm that one

Comment: actually i am calling searchInWallpaper method under datachange method of another valueeventlistener